# Postgres select from few other tables with relation to main table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some troubles with writing sql query.

I have 3 tables in my postgres database.

```
Table devices:
    - dev_id (PK)
    - device_type (varchar)

Table thermomether_values:
    - status_id (PK)
    - error (boolean)
    - receive_time (datetime)
    - device_id (FK to table devices)
    - value (varchar)

Table camera_values:
    - status_id (PK)
    - error (boolean)
    - receive_time (datetime)
    - device_id (FK to table devices)
    - value (decimal)
```

There is some device types like thermomether, camera etc.

In tables "some_device_values" and "another_device_values" every minute is saved some value read from devices.

Sometimes field "error" is true when there is problem with device.
I would like to get all entries where there is an error (status_id and device_id is enough) but only the newest for each device (sort by receive_time desc and get only first).

Sample data:

```
Table devices:
    dev_id  device_type
    1       THERMOMETHER
    2       CAMERA
    3       AC
    4       THERMOMETHER
    5       CAMERA

Table thermomether_values:
    status_id  error  receive_time      device_id  value
    1          false  09-12-2016 10:30  1          36.5*C
    2          false  09-12-2016 10:30  4          15.0*C
    3          false  09-12-2016 10:31  1          36.5*C
    4          false  09-12-2016 10:32  1          36.5*C
    5          true   09-12-2016 10:32  4          10.5*C
    6          true   09-12-2016 10:33  4          11.5*C


Table camera_values:
    status_id  error  receive_time      device_id  value
    1          false  09-12-2016 10:30  2          54.23
    2          true   09-12-2016 10:31  2          0.0
    3          false  09-12-2016 10:31  5          50.76
    4          true   09-12-2016 10:32  2          0.0
    5          true   09-12-2016 10:32  5          -1.0
    6          false  09-12-2016 10:33  2          54.3
```

From the above data output should be:

```
status_id  device_id
6          4          (thermomether)
5          5          (camera)
```

It's a bit complicated to me and I don't know where to start. Can you help me?

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

What about window function?

Here is some small stupid example:

```
with srcdata as (
  select * 
  from (values(10,1,'A'),(10, 2,'B'),(11,1,'X'),(11,2,'Z')) as t(device,event, value) 
)
select * 
from (
  select *, row_number() over w as rowid 
  from srcdata 
  window w as (partition by device order by event)
) a
where rowid=1
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: you can simplify that to `with srcdata (device, event, value) as ( values (....)` - the `select from values` is not needed